# Verbosity of std::optional

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is an example in my code, using `std::optional`:

```
Max = index(summary_max.value(), clusters[summary_max.value()]->Maximum().value());
```

Here, `summary_max` and `Maximum()` is `std::optional`. This is WAY verbose.
I want to type just `index(summary_max, clusters[summary_max]->Maximum());`

Why doesn't `std::optional<T>` support implicit casting to `T`? Is there any valid, inevitable rationale?

Comment: Use `*summary_max` then.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Good, I learned something today

Comment: Have you considered that you're overusing `optional`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are certain your optional objects does indeed have values, you could use the [`operator*` operator function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) instead of the [`value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) member function:

```
Max = index(*summary_max, 
            *(clusters[*summary_max]->Maximum()));
// rant: looks more like C than C++ to me.
```

But as you are using the stored valued of `summary_max` twice, you may simply want to extract (copy/const ref) prior to using it in `index(...)` invocation.

```
const auto& max_index = summary_max.value();
Max = index(max_index, *(clusters[max_index]->Maximum()));
```

Comment: yeah - `const auto& val = *summary_max; Max = index(val, clusters[val]->Maximum());`

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't std::optional support implicit [conversion] to T? Is there any valid, inevitable rationale?

It can't! The presence of the `T` is *optional*. If there isn't one set, what should an implicit conversion do? Produce a default-constructed `T`? That's not even always possible.

The library therefore makes you decide what should happen, and this can be done either with `value()` or by simply dereferencing (if you're sure there *is* a value).

But there's no need for this technique to be terribly verbose:

```
const auto& val         = summary_max.value();
const auto& cluster_max = clusters[val]->Maximum().value();

Max = index(val, cluster_max);
```

As an aside, "casting" means "explicit conversion", so there's no such thing as an "implicit cast". ;)